# How to customize date colors in ant design datapicker for specific dates?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have an object with a date and color in which the current date should be painted. How to determine the current day with the date in the datepicker in ant design.
When I try to get the current month in the dateRender method, I get all the months that are on this tab.

My code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { DatePicker, Space } from "antd";
import moment from "moment";

const dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD";

const data = [{ date: "2021-05-02", color: "green" }];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Space direction="vertical" size={12}>
    <DatePicker
      format={dateFormat}
      dateRender={(current) => {
        let day = moment(data[0].date).format("DD");
        let month = moment(data[0].date).format("MM");
        console.log(current.month()); //instead 5 I get 4,5 and 6 
        const style = {};
        if (
          current.date() === Number(day) &&
          current.month() === Number(month)
        ) {
        
          style.border = "1px solid #1890ff";
          style.borderRadius = "50%";
          style.backgroundColor = data[0].color;
        }
        return (
          <div className="ant-picker-cell-inner" style={style}>
            {current.date()}
          </div>
        );
      }}
    />
  </Space>,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

So how I can get correct current mounth?

Comment: What is current here? Please share the code that involves creating or changing the variable.

Comment: Your code is working for me. Just a minor update the moment month is 0 based so you need to add 1 to the check like `current.month() +1 === Number(month) `